# Gigya gamification for poll

Tags: gigya

I am using GIGYA gamification custom actions for a POLL in a website. As per the documentation I have created a Custom Action. Then, I created a html page which has the poll layout and included Gigya's api key and used gigya.gm.notifyAction function. My questions are -

1. This function as per my understanding will notify the custom action. How can I and where will i see the results. Do i need to use another function to get the counts.
2. Can someone provide a small custom JS code for Gigya.

Answer (score 1):

We do have an example site which will show you how this is implemented. Although the site uses loyalty, you should be able to adapt it to what you want it to show using gamification. The url is: http://raas-demo.gigya.com/

You can also download the websites source code as well.

This will explain about:
http://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Loyalty

Kind Regards

Nadeem R